# How to check two or three conditions in php

Tags: php

I have to check emc value and contact value but I want a specific error message for emc and contact without using `elseif`.

```
if ($emc > 0 || strlen($contact)!=10 || !is_numeric($contact)){
    $emailerror="E-mail id is already registred";
    $contacterror="Wrong Number";
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want two separate if statements, but it's not very clear

Comment: try shorthand if/else ternary operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 separate IF statements to check values, like following :

```
$emailerror = '';
$contacterror = '';
if ($emc > 0)
{
    $emailerror="E-mail id is already registred";
}
if (strlen($contact)!=10 || !is_numeric($contact))
{
    $contacterror="Wrong Number";
}
```

Also you can use ternary operators as well ::

```
$emailerror   = ( $emc > 0 ) ? "E-mail id is already registred" : "";
$contacterror = ( strlen($contact)!=10 || !is_numeric($contact) ) ? "Wrong Number" : "";
```